# Conjugate beam (M/EI)

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I dont understand how the diagram of M/EI of conjugate beam drawn , can someone explain about it ? 
According to conjugate beam theorem , i know that the M/EI represent the w(x) , which is force per unit length of the beam . I dont understand why the author draw in in 2 directions ( upwards and downwards) ... 
[image: ddd]

Comment: Anyone can reply ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the conjugate beam method is to find deflection and slope of the beam.

This method uses equilibrium equations in conjugate beam, instead of using moment area diagram in real beam.

First, you must know the support of both real and conjugate beams, and then you  [transform](http://www.mathalino.com/sites/default/files/reviewer-strength/06-beam-deflections/conjugate_support_real_support.gif) the support of the real beam to the support of the conjugate beam, and draw it.

Second, you plot the M/EI of "real beam" on the conjugate beam.

Finally, you take the equilibrium equations and determine the reactions at the conjugate beams. The reactions of the conjugate beam, V and M, will equal to θ and Δ, respectively, for the real beam.