# An interpretation of the slope-deflection method (or displacement method)

Tags: structural-analysis

I want to be sure that the way I like to think about the displacement method of analysis is correct.

Suppose that a beam as given by the figure below is to be solved. [image]

Under this conditions, the only unknown is the rotation of joint $B$, $\alpha_B$.
As I see it, the steps taken to compute $\alpha_B$ are:

i) apply a moment $M_B^F$ at point $B$ of the beam such that no rotation of $B$ takes place. Such a moment is clockwise. Due to this, node $B$ is under the action of an equal and opposite moment of anticlockwise direction and, therefore, according to the standard conventions, of positive value $PL/8$, and, as such, not in equilibrium;

ii) for node B to be in equilibrium, as it effectively is in the original structure, apply at beam $B$ a moment whose value will depend on $\alpha$; Node $B$ will be subject to an equal and opposite moment $M(\alpha_B)$ such that $$M(\alpha_B)+ PL/8=0$$

Is this a correct interpretation of this method of analysis?

Comment: Have you searched before posting? A similar question was answered recently - if you find it before me that’s fine...

Comment: Yes, I did. But I didn't find anything satisfying.

Comment: This seems relevant : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/13444/10902

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it doesn't help me that much. But let me ask you: would you accept what I've written as acceptable?

Comment: How did you get PL/8?

Comment: No, it isn't. If you are using the simplest of beam deflection theory, then the unknown is normally taken as the deflection curve as a function of x. It has two regions, one either side of P. So you have 2 functions, f1(x) and f2(x), and the constraint that they have to join smoothly at P (df1/dx|P =df2/dx|P). The fixation constraints are that df1(0)/dx = 0, f1(0) = 0 and f2(B) = 0.

Comment: I used the results found in this table of fixed-end moments:  https://www.slideshare.net/AnasCivil/table-of-fixed-end-moments-formulas .

@PhilSweet, the approach that I take is just slightly different than the one usually taken in the textbooks. In the end I get the same set of equations. I'm far from convinced by this approach, otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. So, could you tell me directly what is wrong whith what I've written? I don't understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You should get same final result as the table you gave in comment, this kind of tables are formulas obtained by solving indeterminate beam. 
There is procedure for solving statically indeterminate beams as you can see in the following link  [slope deflection](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.civil.iitb.ac.in/~minamdar/ce317/Lectures/Slope-Deflection.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi8-dbF8rzYAhVOJ1AKHTnvD38QFgi6ATAc&usg=AOvVaw0lFZI0628bKVYKvzE2KhB0). Those solutions should guide you to solve your problem.

Keep in mind basics for real beam from theory of conjugate beam
[image: conjugate beam]

Comment: I actually haven't solved the problem, so I don't know of which solution you're talking about.

Comment: I have mistaken your last formula for solution M at B as it is obviously 0. Sorry this simbols mix on my phone from time to time. Though author of document in my link provides solution of similar problem in example 12.2.

Comment: It's OK. I already knew about the tables provided by you, but hank you, anyway.

Comment: At B beam is free to rotate so MB equals 0 that is one condition and you have to determine moment at A. Maybe revise your question?

Comment: No, the point is to compute the rotation of point A. And I'm trying to be sure that I understand the logic of the displacement method, not the computations that go along with it.

Comment: In previous comment I was talking about first part where you say that B is under moment. It is supported at B, free to rotate and moment equals 0, at A there is no rotation and moment is unknown, angle of rotation at A due to fixed end is 0. I think your first assumption does not agree with physical state of beam from your example. I updated my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry: I wanted to say the rotation of the beam at point B. The approach that I gave above is given in a swiss book in French by two professors at the École Polytechnique fédérale de Lausanne. But I'm not sure that I'm correctly reading what they wrote.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Hibbeler? I like his books and had planned to do some calculation using this method also for some frame we built.

Comment: Yes, I took a look at Hibbeler (and other books as well). I dont't like much its approach. And I'm not saying it's a bad approach (it would be silly to think that). It just doesn't appeal to my intuition.